# In Node.js design patterns unleashing zalgo why is the asynchronous path consistent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, zalgo

In the great book i'm reading now `NodeJs design patterns` I see the following example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var cache = {};

function inconsistentRead(filename, callback) {
    if (cache[filename]) {
        //invoked synchronously
        callback(cache[filename]);
    } else {
        //asynchronous function
        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            cache[filename] = data;
            callback(data);
        });
    }
}
```

then:

```
function createFileReader(filename) {
    var listeners = [];
    inconsistentRead(filename, function(value) {
        listeners.forEach(function(listener) {
            listener(value);
        });
    });
    return {
        onDataReady: function(listener) {
            listeners.push(listener);
        }
    };
}
```

and usage of it:

```
var reader1 = createFileReader('data.txt');
reader1.onDataReady(function(data) {
console.log('First call data: ' + data);
```

The author says that if the item is in cache the behaviour is synchronous and asynchronous if its not in cache.  I'm ok with that.  he then continues to say that we should be either sync or async.  I'm ok with that.

What I don't understand is that if I take the asynchronous path then when this line `var reader1 = createFileReader('data.txt');` is executed can't the asynchronous file read finish already and thus the listener **won't** be registered in the following line which tries to register it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript will never interrupt a function to run a different function.

The "file has been read" handler will be queued until the JavaScript event loop is free.

Comment: I didn't understand cant the file finish reading in between `var reader1 = createFileReader('data.txt');` // file finished reading here and the next line: 
`reader1.onDataReady(function(data) {`

Comment: @Jas — In theory it could, but that makes no difference because the data ready event handler won't be called until the JS event loop isn't busy running the function it is in the middle of.

Comment: @Jas Your mistake here is in thinking that the callback will run as soon as the read is done. It will not. The callback will run a some future point after the read is done, when the call stack is clear and there are no other events in the queue ahead of it. (While another function is running, the call stack is non-empty, so the event caused by the completed file-read must wait its turn.)

Comment: @Quentin Is it possible that `var reader1 = createFileReader('data.txt');` is run, then the file read finishes, then there would be no events in event loop, then next line `reader1.onDataReady(function(data)` is run? or is the thing failing my theory is that the call stack is is non-empty.  i don't get why is it waiting for the call stack to be empty?

Comment: @Jas — The two lines you quote in your last comment are **in the same function**, the JavaScript event loop will be in the middle of running **that function** so any events that come in will be put in a queue until that function (and the function that called it, and so on all the way back up the stack) are finished.

Comment: @Quentin wow thanks I didn't know that.  that solves my problem!

Answer (score 2):

The async read operation won't call its callback or start emitting events until after the current tick of the event loop, so the sync code that registers the event listener will run first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I feel the same when read this part of the book.
"inconsistentRead looks good"

But in the next paragraphs I will explain the potential bug this kind of sync/async functions "could" produce when used (so it could not pass too).

As a summary, was happen in the sample of use is:

In an event cycle 1:

reader1 is created, cause "data.txt" isn't cached yet, it will respond async in other event cycle N.

some callbacks are subscribed for reader1 readiness. And will be called on cycle N.

In event cycle N:
"data.txt" is read and this is notified and cached, so reader1 subscribed callbacks are called.

In event cycle X (but X >= 1, but X could be before or after N): (maybe a timeout, or other async path schedule this)
reader2 is created for the same file "data.txt"

What happens if:
X === 1 : The bug could express in a no mentioned way, cause the data.txt result will attempt to cache twice, the first read, the more fast, will win. But reader2 will register its callbacks before the async response is ready, so they will be called.

X > 1 AND X < N: Happens the same as X === 1

X > N : the bug will express as explained in the book:

You create reader2 (the response for it is already cached), the onDataReady is called cause the data is cached (but you don't subscribe any subscriber yet), and after that yo subscribe the callbacks with onDataReady, but this will not be called again.

X === N: Well, this is an edge case, and if the reader2 portion run first will pass the same as X === 1, but, if run after "data.txt" readiness portion of inconsistentRead then will happen the same as when X > N

Answer (score 0):

this example was more helpful for me to understand this concept

```
const fs = require('fs');
const cache = {};

function inconsistentRead(filename, callback) {
    if (cache[filename]) {
        console.log("load from cache")
        callback(cache[filename]);
    } else {
        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            cache[filename] = data;
            callback(data);
        });
    }
}

function createFileReader(filename) {
    const listeners = [];
    inconsistentRead(filename, function (value) {
        console.log("inconsistentRead CB")
        listeners.forEach(function (listener) {
            listener(value);
        });
    });
    return {
        onDataReady: function (listener) {
            console.log("onDataReady")
            listeners.push(listener);
        }
    };
}

const reader1 = createFileReader('./data.txt');
reader1.onDataReady(function (data) {
    console.log('First call data: ' + data);
})

setTimeout(function () {
    const reader2 = createFileReader('./data.txt');
    reader2.onDataReady(function (data) {
        console.log('Second call data: ' + data);
    })
}, 100)
```

output:

```
╰─ node zalgo.js        
onDataReady
inconsistentRead CB
First call data: :-)
load from cache
inconsistentRead CB
onDataReady
```

when the call is async the `onDataReady` handler is set before file is read and in the async the the itration finishes before `onDataReady` is setting the listener

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem can also be illustrated with a simpler example:

```
let gvar = 0;
let add = (x, y, callback) => { callback(x + y + gvar) }
add(3,3, console.log); gvar = 3
```

In this case, `callback` is invoked immediately inside `add`, so the change of `gvar` afterwards has no effect: `console.log(3+3+0)`

On the other hand, if we add asynchronously

```
let add2 = (x, y, callback) => { setImmediate(()=>{callback(x + y + gvar)})}
add2(3, 3, console.log); gvar = 300
```

Because the order of execution, `gvar=300` runs before the async call `setImmediate`, so the result becomes `console.log( 3 + 3 + 300)`

In Haskell, you have pure function vs monad, which are similar to "async" functions that get executed "later". In Javascript these are not explicitly declared. So these "delayed" executed code can be difficult to debug.